# Ruby on Rails - Bundler can not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I have Rails 2.3.8 installed for maintenance of legacy code for a client. The problem is that I cannot run bundler install because it fails after producing the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 2.3.8) ruby depends on
      activerecord (= 2.3.8) ruby

    activerecord (2.3.11)
```

My Gmefile is

```
source :gemcutter

# == Application Gems
gem "rails", "2.3.8"
gem "activesupport"
gem "mysql", "2.8.1"
gem "devise", "1.0.8"
gem "inherited_resources", "1.0.6"
gem "will_paginate", "2.3.14"
gem "canable", "0.1.1", :require => 'canable'
gem "aasm", "2.1.5", :require => "aasm"
gem "fastercsv", "1.5.3", :require => 'fastercsv'
gem "jnunemaker-validatable", :require => 'validatable'
gem "thinking-sphinx", "1.3.18"
gem "delayed_job", "2.1.0.pre"
gem "ts-delayed-delta", "1.1.0", :require => "thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta"
gem "erubis"
gem "cloudfiles"
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'json'
gem 'cocaine'
gem 'fog', '~> 0.9.0'

# requires exiftool (command line utility) to be installed!
#  http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html
gem "mini_exiftool", "2.4.2"
gem "rack-killswitch"
gem "carmen"
gem "rest-client"

# == Deployment Gems
gem "capistrano"
gem "capistrano-ext"

# Visual email testing in the browser
gem "mail_view", :group => :development

# == Test Gems
group :test do
  gem "shoulda", "2.11.1"
  gem "machinist", "1.0.3"
  gem "faker", "0.3.1"
  gem "mocha", "0.9.8"
  gem "timecop", "0.3.4"
  gem "cucumber", "0.8.5"
  gem "cucumber-rails", "0.3.2"
  gem "webrat" # needed for cucumber
  gem "database_cleaner", "0.5.0" # needed for cucumber
  gem "sinatra", "1.0"
  gem "rack-contrib"
  gem "artifice"
end
```

I have added `gem "activerecord", "2.3.8"` with no success because it then says, bundler is locked to 2.3.11.

Is anyone able to able.

Comment: Is this a brand new Gemfile?  Or did you modify it so that it previously had `gem "rails", "2.3.11"`, and now it has `2.3.8`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`bundle update activerecord`

that should handle the specific version of active record

Odds are that one of the other gems locked you to Rails 2.3.11 (ActiveRecord 2.3.11). You can see what depends on what in the Gemfile.lock.

Another option is to delete the Gemfile.lock and run bundle again.

Comment: You probably should also change your source to rubygems!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error, hope that it helps some one else

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    jsonb_accessor (~> 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 5.0)

    kaminari (= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
        activerecord

    paper_trail (~> 8) was resolved to 8.1.2, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.2, < 5.2)

    rails (~> 5.2) was resolved to 5.2.1.rc1, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.2.1.rc1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.2)

    api_blueprint was resolved to 0.1.2, which depends on
      rails
```

In my case I was trying to update rails. What solved was figuring out the gem that has a dependency for activerecord < 5.2 (`paper_trail`, in this case). The solution was downgrade papertrail to the version 5.2 and after this I was able to update rails to a version greater than 5.2